# Problem running the tidyverse package?

Tags: r

I installed the R "tidyverse" package, but when I try to run it, it gives me this error:

```
package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.2.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.0 is required
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: You are having version conflicts, always install all the independencies as well

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by the following way

1. First updated R

   install.packages("installr")

   library(installr)

   updateR()
2. Second install package `ggplot2`

   install.packages("ggplot2") // `rlang` install as a dependency with `ggplot2`
3. Finally install package `tidyverse`

   install.packages("tidyverse")

Hope you can solve your problem by following the above way.